Exponential series with fractional exponents $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\delta n}}{\Gamma(\delta n+1)}$
$$
\mbox{I´m trying to prove that}\quad
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\delta n}}{\Gamma(\delta n+1)}\quad\mbox{converges on}\ \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}
$$

For $\delta =1$ we would simpy have $\exp\left(x\right)$ but I´m mostly curious about the case for $\delta \in \left(0,1/2\right)$.
My attempt was to prove it with the ratio test, but this just leaves me with a term
$$
O\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\delta n + 1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\delta\left(n + 1\right) + 1\right)}\right)
$$
I have numerical evidence that this converges to $0$ for $n \to \infty$, but couldn't prove it myself.


When you see a gamma function, think immediately about Stirling approximation.

If $\delta =\frac{1}{3}$ we get: $\frac{3}{80} e^x \left(\frac{9 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},x\right)}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{8}{3}\right)}+\frac{80 \Gamma
\left(\frac{2}{3},x\right)}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)}+80\right)$

$$f(\delta)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\delta n}}{\Gamma(\delta n+1)}=E_{\delta }\left(x^{\delta }\right)$$ where appears  the Mittag-Leffler function.
$$\delta=\frac 12\quad \implies \quad f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=e^x \text{erfc}\left(-\sqrt{x}\right)$$
I do not know other cases with fractional exponent.
If
$$a_n= \frac{x^{\delta n}}{\Gamma(\delta n+1)}\quad \implies \quad \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=x^\delta\frac{\Gamma (n \delta +1)}{\Gamma ((n +1)\delta+1)}$$
Taking logarithms, using Stirling expansion and exponentiating again
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left(\frac{x}{\delta  n}\right)^{\delta }\Bigg(1-\frac{\delta +1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \Bigg)$$

Thank you very much, I haven't heard of the ML-function so far.

@oliH.. Don't worry ! It will be soon. Cheers -:)
